# Selenium - mulltiple buttons with the same type [python]

Tags: python, selenium, class, button, nested

I am trying to click on a button using selenium, and the only selector I can use is button's type. The problem is that there are two buttons with the same type on the webpage. And the problem is that I cannot control which one I am selecting. Currently, I am using:

````
```inputElement=fox.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']")```
````

However, this selects only the first button, not the second one.  I think the solution would be to somehow identify button which lives inside a class which lives inside a different class. Is it possible to do something like that? I am documenting the problem below:

[image]

[image: The button I cannot fetch]

The first image is the one where the button is fetched with the line of code I gave, and the second one is the one where I cannot fetch the button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are interest in the xpath then, you can do multiple things like indexing or giving just the text between button tag.

you can do something like this :

```
fox.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='submit'])[2]")
```

or

```
fox.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit' and contains(text(), 'Ponisti')]")
```

for second button, just change this `Ponisti` to the button text

there are still few more ways to differentiate buttons.